# How can i display object items as separate strings into an mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs

What i have so far is

```
  $mdDialog.show(
    $mdDialog.alert()
    .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('Discount comanda')
    .textContent(paymentNotifications.join())
    .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
    .ok('Am inteles')
    )
```

I want that the items from paymentNotifications to be displayed as separate strings. At this moment, the items are displayed on a single line like this "This code is the first one, This code is the second one".

I want them displayed like that

```
 This code is the first one, 
 This code is the second one
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.htmlContent()` and have to import `angular-sanitize.js` in your html and load `ngSanitize` as in module dependency. Like :

```
 var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngSanitize', //... other modules//]);
```

then your code should be like :

```
$mdDialog.show(
    $mdDialog.alert()
    .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('Discount comanda')
    .htmlContent(paymentNotifications.join('<br>'))
    .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
    .ok('Am inteles')
    );
```